# How to combine output and input redirection

Tags: unix, command-line, io-redirection

I would like to combine output and input redirection in the same command line.

For instance, I have an `input` file that I use as input to a progam. And the output of the program needs to be stored in an `output` file.

Can I write something like `./program < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly valid

Comment: Just don't use the same file for both.